# How to allow only opening files in current directory in Python3?

Tags: python, security, filenames

I am writing a simple file server in Python. The filename is provided by the client and should be considered untrusted. How to verify that it corresponds to a file inside the current directory (within it or any of its subdirectories)? Will something like:

```
pwd=os.getcwd()
if os.path.commonpath((pwd,os.path.abspath(filename))) == pwd:
    open(filename,'rb')
```

suffice?

Comment: what about https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve ?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the filename to a canonical path using [`os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath), get the directory portion, and see if the current directory (in canonical form) is a prefix of that:

```
import os, os.path

def in_cwd(fname):
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(fname))
    return path.startswith(os.getcwd())
```

By converting `fname` to a canonical path we handle symbolic links and paths containing `../`.

---

**Update**

Unfortunately, the above code has a little problem. For example,

```
'/a/b/cd'.startswith('/a/b/c')
```

returns `True`, but we definitely *don't* want that behaviour here! Fortunately, there's an easy fix: we just need to append `os.sep` to the paths before performing the prefix test. The new version also handles any OS pathname case-insensitivity issues via [`os.path.normcase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase).

```
import os, os.path

def clean_dirname(dname):
    dname = os.path.normcase(dname)
    return os.path.join(dname, '')

def in_cwd(fname):
    cwd = clean_dirname(os.getcwd())
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(fname))
    path = clean_dirname(path)
    return path.startswith(cwd)
```

Thanks to DSM for pointing out the flaw in the previous code.

---

Here's a version that's a little more efficient. It uses [`os.path.commonpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonpath), which is more robust than appending `os.sep` and doing a string prefix test.

```
def in_cwd(fname):
    cwd = os.path.normcase(os.getcwd())
    path = os.path.normcase(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(fname)))
    return os.path.commonpath((path, cwd)) == cwd
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution. I tried running it with my test cases and it seems to fail for the non-existent file case, though (e.g. `foo.py`). As in it returns true instead of false. Edit: but that may not matter. OP seems happy to let `open` potentially receive (and throw exceptions) when receiving non-existent files. So +1.

Comment: @Tagc I've just updated my answer, so I need to update my previous comment too. :) If `in_cwd` returns `True` you can then test if the file actually exists if you want to serve the file. There's actually a benefit in having `in_cwd` returning `True` on valid paths for files that don't yet exist: you can use it to validate a proposed path for a file that's being saved to the cwd.

Comment: This also has the problem that if `fname` is the current directory name, this succeeds, when it should fail. ie `in_cwd("cwd_folder") -> True.` Considering the input is untrusted, we should not give details of internal folder names.

Comment: @TheMatt Fair point, and it also returns True if `fname` is a subdirectory in the current directory tree. But we can use `isdir` or `isfile` from `os.path` to handle those cases.